# How to bind observablecollection to a textblock within a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have ListBox that is bound to a list.  Within the list, i have an observable collection called "AttributePath".  What I am struggling with is how to bind a Textblock (used as a tooltip) to the ObservableCollection "AttributePath."  Here is the xmal-

```
        <ListBox 
            Name="lstCandidates" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UIProperties.CandidateAttributes}"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                        <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UIProperties.CandidateAttributes.AttributePath}" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <TextBlock Text="Last updated: "/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel.ToolTip>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The line with {Binding UIProperties.CandidateAttributes.AttributePath} is where this fails.   Just not sure of the syntax to set the itemsource for the textblock.

Comment: why you are binding list with the Textblock? You should bind list with the listbox and property with the textblock

Comment: simple, i am new to wpf.  The AttributePath is a property of the CandidateAttributes list.  Each CondidateAttributes can have on or more AttributePath that belongs to that row.  Idea was to add observablecollection to the list, and then bind the textblock to the AttributePath property.  Can you show me an example or other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Bind directly the property `AttributePath` :

```
<StackPanel.ToolTip>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributePath}" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Last updated: "/>
         </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel.ToolTip>
```

However if AttributePath is a collection you could use an ItemsControl to show it:

```
<StackPanel.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AttributePath}">
               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Last updated: "/>
             </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel.ToolTip>
```

You can also decide how to display the item inside the collection setting an appropriate `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Getting closer.  on the UI the tooltip displays "Collection" instead of the actual data

Comment: Use the itemcontrol as showed in the last part of the answer